# Rails new form -> nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

The task model has just one field : title.

I've made a form to add a new task with one single field : title

But in the create method, we can see that title is filled by "test"

but in the query, we can see "nil" ... any ideas ?

thanks

```
Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-03 13:16:44 -0500
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iWaK1QX6VCyeUCueLrRNErJEtdm/ZNxg4d3LU0vKjnY=", "task"=>{"title"
=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Add a new task "}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 03  Jan 2013 18:16:44 UTC +00:00], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 03 Jan 2013 18:16:44 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/tasks
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

here is the create method

```
  def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:post])

    if @task.save
      redirect_to tasks_path, :notice => "Task successfully saved"  
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the controller code for TasksController#create at the very least.

Comment: I've just edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are fetching `post` instead of `task`

```
@task = Task.new(params[:task])
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your attribute is *accessible* or you won't be able to mass-assign changes to it:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
end
```

You should have unit tests that properly exercise your models to be sure that they can be updated as you do in the controller. Those will quickly uncover any attributes which have not been correctly flagged.

Rails 2.3 and prior were not strict about this, you could mass-assign anything, but Rails 3 will not assign these attributes unless they are specifically allowed.

Comment: [Jiří Pospíšil](http://stackoverflow.com/users/19093/jiri-pospisil) has an observation worth noting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

> attr_accessible :title

is in your Task model (task.rb)

**UPDATE:**
change params[:post] to params[:task]:

```
@task = Task.new(params[:task])
```

Answer (score -2):

In your tasks_controller.rb , you must have create method which will handle `POST` request and accept parameters which are passed though request .

```
  def create 
    task = Task.new(params[:task]) 
    task.save
  end
```

Comment: This doesn't even seem like Ruby. What is that supposed to mean? Arguments are not declared with square brackets.

Comment: You should definitely *not* ignore the return value of save.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil yeah i know ... just to make it simple so that person can understand its logic